# Share a thread pool among processes in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is there a way in python to create a thread pool that i could later access from several processes that were forked using python multiprocessing? 
I need this feature because i have component that could only be paralleled using multiprocessing and another component that could be paralleled using multithreading 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to share one variable between threads/processes?

Comment: Forking a process with a thread pool creates a new process with its own thread pool. You can not really share such a pool between processes.

Comment: @DYD no im trying to use the same threads between processes